# spring-data-jdbc readOnly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jdbc

I'm trying to make some field **readOnly** -> *insert* and *update* aka *save()* should not send that field to DB but the field should be populated with *select*.

**@ReadOnlyProperty** from org.springframework.data.annotation.ReadOnlyProperty does not do the trick.

**versions:** spring-boot: 2.2.0.RC1, spring-data-jdbc: 1.1.0.RELEASE, spring-data-commons: 2.2.0.RELEASE

**db:** MSSQL

[spring-data-jdbc readOnly](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/blob/4434a0f5526adf1ebf20de9c690fab142ceab883/spring-data-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jdbc/core/convert/SqlGenerator.java#L626)

Should it work and is there any other way to do it?

NOTE: please don't mix spring-data-jdbc with spring-data-jpa

```
import java.util.Set;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.ReadOnlyProperty;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.MappedCollection;

public class Organization {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @Column("readOnlyProperty")
    @ReadOnlyProperty
    private String readOnlyProperty;
    @ReadOnlyProperty
    @MappedCollection
    private Set<Employee> employees;
}
```

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

public class Employee {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

```
@Test
public void insert() {
    // insert should not set readOnlyProperty
    Organization organization = new Organization("org1", "readOnly");
    Employee employee = new Employee("emp1");
    Set<Employee> employess = new HashSet<>();
    employess.add(employee);
    organization.setEmployees(employess);
    organizationRepository.save(organization);
}
```

**LOG:**
 Executing prepared SQL statement [INSERT INTO organization (name, readOnlyProperty) VALUES (?, ?)]

Executing prepared SQL statement [INSERT INTO employee (name, organization) VALUES (?, ?)]

Comment: do you have an example project to look at? Or at least the code for your entity?

Comment: @JensSchauder code added. If it is necessary I will add project url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug.
I created [DATAJDBC-431](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-431) for it and it will probably fixed in the next service release.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test, but according to [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Basic_Attributes#Insertable.2C_Updatable_.2F_Read_Only_Fields_.2F_Returning)

> The Column annotation and XML element defines insertable and updatable options. These allow for this column, or foreign key field to be omitted from the SQL INSERT or UPDATE statement. These can be used if constraints on the table prevent insert or update operations. They can also be used if multiple attributes map to the same database column, such as with a foreign key field through a ManyToOne and Id or Basic mapping. Setting both insertable and updatable to false, effectively mark the attribute as read-only.

```
@Column(name="COLUMN_NAME",updatable=false, insertable=false)
private String fieldName;
```

should make the field read-only.

Comment: please see NOTE above:

"NOTE: please don't mix spring-data-jdbc with spring-data-jpa"

Comment: @mpDeveloped please share your code, then we can provide better answer. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
    https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example